# Require python modules libraries when i run my standalone software in another laptop

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

i have all required python module libraries for my standalone software in my main laptop.But if i run my software in another laptop,it is getting errors.Do i have to reinstall those python modules(eg.PySide2,PyQt)?Or should i copy or install modules into my software folder using this command?

```
pip install --target=d:\somewhere\other\than\the\default package_name
```

you know what i mean?i dont see any solution for this kind of post.So is this question weird or how do software developer do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work in more than one laptop, I would recommend working in a virtual environment. This will allow you to install all the dependencies at once.

1. First, you should  [create the virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/venv.html)
2. Then, in order to get all the libraries in your pc, use `pip freeze`. When you have them, create a requirements.txt in the root folder and include them in there.
3. When you [activate the virtual environment and gotten inside of it](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/venv.html), use the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` in order to install the libraries that you were using in the other pc.